# App is published on Play Store but not indexed for downloads

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on Google Play Store on 13th Dec. Link below for quick reference.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.falsecaller

It has got few downloads by accessing the link, but if I try to search the app by its name False Caller in play store, it lists apps with similar names like Fake Caller.
Purpose of Fake Caller apps & my app False Caller is no way related. Neither in the big list of Fake caller apps, considering name similarity my app is still not listed.
What is something, more I need to do, in order to have easy access for downloads to my app ? Practically during marketing talks, I cannot keep communicating this link above for users to encourage download my app.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your App is that low in Rank thatGoogle just prefers the other ones.

But you can shearch for  `com.falsecaller` or `"False Caller"`
[image]